# Aligned starts of subscript and superscripts

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

What's the code for this one?

[image: must be like this]

I've tried this code:

```
{{a_1}^{{j_1} \left(g \right)}}{{a_2}^{{j_2} \left(g \right)}}{{a_3}^{{j_3} \left(g \right)}} \ldots
```

But I got this:

[image: results]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Omit braces around the a’s, that is, `a_1^{j_1}`, etc.  Also, you don’t need `\left` and `\right` here!

Comment: Remove almost all braces: `a_1^{j_1(g)} a_2^{j_2(g)} a_3^{j_3(g)} \dotsm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Drop the double pairs of curly braces around `a_1`, `a_2` and `a_3`
- Drop all `\left` and `\right` modifiers -- they do absolutely nothing here *except* create code clutter

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman clone
\begin{document}
\[
a_1^{j_1(g)} a_2^{j_2(g)} a_3^{j_3(g)} \dots
\]
\end{document}
```